# How to move docker images to other drive in windows

Tags: windows, docker

I try to run the following [script](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-could-i-install-docker-for-windows-on-drive-e-my-ssd-c-is-full/52347) but `dockerd` is not recognized in my workstation.

My OS is windows 10. Just installed the latest version of docker that is 18.09.2

It is my first time with docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find other way to do it based on [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-run-docker-containers-on-a-different-drive-than-system-drive/47669) post.

For Unix containers, the path for images can be changed by Docker Desktop interface, at settings form. But if you use the windows containers feature then a second service is installed, the "Docker Engine". To change the image folder for this service do the following steps:

1) Get the path to the config file.
Go to Administrative tools->Services. 
Check docker demon command line for service "Dock Engine"

[image]

The command line is something like

> > "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\dockerd.exe" --run-service --service-name docker -G myPc" --config-file C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\tmp-d4w\daemon.json

2) Edit the config file `daemon.json` and add the data-root property.Property value should point to desired location. Should look something like this. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for information on json structure.

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false,
  "hosts": [
  "npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine_windows"
  ],
  "data-root":"D:\\Docker\\data-root"
```

}

If necessary, give permissions for the running account to access the folder.

3) restart the service.
If doesn't start, check `eventlog` for possible errors.

Previous configured data in c:\ProgramData\Docker will be lost when you change the install location.
It’s like a new install to a new location. (images, containers, etc). All sub folders will be created again.

To keep the minimum on system drive do this on a fresh install.

I am not 100% sure about this solution, but so far, docker is working fine and system drive occupation is slim.

Answer (score 22):

This answer is more an addition at [Jean-François Beauchamp's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1020742/467852) :
You can find full documentation about this config file on [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/).

It is stated :

> `--data-root` is the path where persisted data such as images, volumes, and cluster state are stored.

and

> `--exec-root` is the path where the container state is stored. The default value is /var/run/docker. Specify the path for your running daemon here.

So if you want to move both your containers and images (and the other stuff), you have to set both of these parameter.

You can also create a simple link where Docker expects its folder to redirect to the desired place.
It is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54904628/7740405) and lead to the same result. It looks "dirty" but in the end it looks more stable than the first solution.

---

#### Working with WSL 2 engine (for Windows Home and Family Editions)

`"D:\\Docker\\data-root"` value as [suggested by Miguel](https://serverfault.com/a/975998/467852) will crash Docker because it has to be a WSL folder.
However, Docker create a specific WSL distro which contains your docker data, [and you can move it](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5829). This does not require to modify dockerd parameters.

To move docker's WSL distro

```
 wsl --export docker-desktop-data docker-desktop-data.tar
 wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data
 wsl --import docker-desktop-data X:\wslStore\ docker-desktop-data.tar --version 2
```

The `X:\wslStore` param is the path where you want to "mount" your Distro, something like `D:\Docker\data-root`

Comment: I used the WSL 2 approach and my data in `c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data` was indeed move to the new location. I still have data in `...\Docker\wsl\distro` that I would also like to move. Can I do that using the same procedure?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to move the distro "docker-desktop-data" aswell ? If yes than I think you can use the same procedure

Comment: I moved both of them now and it seems to work fine! :)

Comment: The biggest part (mostly images) are stored in docker-desktop-data so I didn't mention moving docker-desktop but I'm glad it worked ! :)

Comment: thx a lot for describing WSL 2

Answer (score 5):

On Docker v19.03.8 for Windows, I added the `graph` parameter to my config, and it worked for me, but apparently, this parameter is deprecated and we should now use `data-root` instead. The default value for `data-root` is `c:\programdata\docker`. Beware that in the JSON configuration file the backslashes need to be escaped.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a link to the docu? Where the handling of `graph` or `data-root` from the config file is explained?

Comment: @KargWare Here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/ and here https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/

Comment: This broke my docker, it cannot start anymore.

Comment: /!\ This answer is OUTDATED, DO NOT TRY THIS WITH WSL 2 /!\
This is for WSL 1 which was basically like Git Bash but more complete. WSL 2 is now used and behaves like a VM and works nothing like WSL 1